# How to check the process of sending mail using swiftmailer/ php?

Tags: php, email, swiftmailer

For instance, i would like to send 10000 mail ,
I have set up the rules of sending 100 per connection, 30 sec wait for another connection, so in the process , how can i know and display ,how much have been sent, how many left?

Thank you.

Here is the swiftmailer plugin that control the speed of sending mail

[anti-flood plugin](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html)

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can to use the [Logger Plugin](http://swiftmailer.org/docs/plugins.html#using-the-logger-plugin) and to parser the log.